# McAfee python script, SSL Failed to Verify

Tags: python-2.7, mcafee

So for my job I have been required to learn Python for McAfee...  Anyway I cannot find any decent documentation, so I thought I would add my notes here and see it anyone can improve on my solutions.

Anyway I have been getting the below error:

```
    Error/reason: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)>
```

My code is below, with private info removed

```
    import mcafee

    mc = mcafee.client("172.16.153.194", "8443","admin","password")

    #code specific to this task
    input = "mytag" #

    systems = mc.system.find(input)#Search text can be IP address, MAC address, user name, agent GUID or tag
    #The above uses the System Tree for searching
    for system in systems:
        #The below file contains EPOComputerProperties
        #the file is in the for loop to all each device to produce results 
    for each property
        file = open('C:/.../.../.../myquery.txt')
        for i in file:
            id = system[i.rstrip('\n')]
            print id
        print ""
        file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution was to use a Monkey patch (an ill advised Monkey patch...)  using the below code at the top of my work:

```
    import ssl

    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

If you can find a better way to achieve the connection, without providing a valid cert for my ePO server please let me know.